Replacing DOI link with a specific text link like CrossRef
I want to replace DOI links made by hyperref package with any word or text link I want because it is very ugly and lengthy at the end of my references. Could anyone help me with that?

I prefer this one:


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You can use the following code:
\DeclareFieldFormat*{doi}{[\href{https://doi.org/#1}{CrossRef}]}

MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{Li,
author = {Z. Li and M.J. Yang and J.S. Park and S.H. Wei and J.J. Berry and K. Zhu},
title = {Stabilizing perovskite structures by tuning tolerance factor: formation of formamidinium and cesium lead iodide solid-state alloys},
journaltitle = {Chem.\ Mater.},
volume = {28},
number = {1},
year = {2016},
pages = {284-292},
doi = {10.1021/acs.chemmater.5b04107},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{doi}{[\href{https://doi.org/#1}{CrossRef}]}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}



Thank you so much for your great help. It worked!
